# How much power supply does a typical PC build need?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I am building a system for a friend. The potential specs are like this so far:

- ASUS A8N-VM motherboard
- AMD Athlon 64 3200+ @ 2.0 GHz
- Any 7200RPM SATA HDD
- Palit GeForce 8800GT 512MB GDDR3 PCIe
- One DVD/CD combo drive
- Creative SB Live! 5.1 sound card

I was wondering what wattage of power supply would be able to support this hardware. I had a 350W in mind... would that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out -> http://www.journeysystems.com/support/calculator/

That power supply might be able to handle that hardware.  I typical computer only uses 200watts or so.

keep in mind though that power supplies are designed to be most efficient at a fraction of the advertised wattage(not sure what the actual percentage is, 75% or so).
so running a computer that actually uses 350 watts is a bad idea because it will put too much stress on the power supply.

Comment: THanks for your answer... I was using other wattage calculators that were way off the number given by that link. Much more accurate... thanks!